# Ordering bars in a stacked bar plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following is a simplified version of my dataframe (without too much loss in generality)

```
sales<-data.frame(ItemID=c(1,3,7,9,10,12),
                  Salesman=c("Bob","Sue","Jane","Bob","Sue","Jane"),
                  ProfitLoss=c(10.00,9.00,9.50,-7.50,-11.00,-1.00))
```

which produces

```
  ItemID Salesman ProfitLoss
1      1      Bob       10.0
2      3      Sue        9.0
3      7     Jane        9.5
4      9      Bob       -7.5
5     10      Sue      -11.0
6     12     Jane       -1.0
```

The following produces a stacked bar plot of each salesman's sales, ordered by the overall profit for each salesman.

```
sales$Salesman<-reorder(sales$Salesman,-sales$ProfitLoss,FUN="sum") #to order the bars
profits<-sales[which(sales$ProfitLoss>0),]
losses<-sales[which(sales$ProfitLoss<0),]
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=losses,aes(x=Salesman, y=ProfitLoss),stat="identity", color="white")+
  geom_bar(data=profits,aes(x=Salesman, y=ProfitLoss),stat="identity", color="white")
```

[image]

This works exactly as I desire.  My issue arises when one of the salesmen has a profit but no loss, or a loss but no profit.  For instance, changing `sales` to

```
sales<-data.frame(ItemID=c(1,3,7,9,10),
                  Salesman=c("Bob","Sue","Jane","Bob","Sue"),
                  ProfitLoss=c(10.00,9.00,9.50,-7.50,-11.00))
```

and reapplying the previous steps produces

[image]

So, the salesman are clearly out of order.  For this example I can cheat and plot my profits before losses like

```
ggplot()+
      geom_bar(data=profits,aes(x=Salesman, y=ProfitLoss),stat="identity", color="white")+
      geom_bar(data=losses,aes(x=Salesman, y=ProfitLoss),stat="identity", color="white")
```

but that won't work for my real dataset.

Edit: In my real dataset, each salesman has more than two sales, and for each salesman I've stacked the bars so that the smallest bars in magnitude are closest to the x axis and the largest bars (i.e. biggest profit, biggest loss) are farthest from the x axis. For this reason, I need to call geom_bar() on both the `profits` dataframe and the `losses` dataframe. (I originally left this information out to try to avoid making my question too complex.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first plot call to geom_bar(losses dataset) only has two levels of salesman, hence the order is changed - that's why calling profits first still works (as there are still all levels). But your reordering works  if you change the plot call

```
sales<-data.frame(ItemID=c(1,3,7,9,10),
              Salesman=c("Bob","Sue","Jane","Bob","Sue"),
              ProfitLoss=c(10.00,9.00,9.50,-7.50,-11.00))

 #to order the bars
sales$Salesman<-reorder(sales$Salesman,-sales$ProfitLoss,FUN="sum")

# Changed plot call
ggplot(sales, aes(x = factor(Salesman), y = ProfitLoss)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="dodge",color="white")
```

[image]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following edit; Do you want the longest bars [ie the largest (profit + abs(losses))] furthest from the y-axis, rather than by descending revenue. You can do this by changing the reorder function. Apologies if i misunderstand.

I changed Jane's data so that it is the longest overall bar

```
sales<-data.frame(ItemID=c(1,3,7,9,10),
              Salesmn=c("Bob","Sue","Jane","Bob","Sue"),
              ProfitLoss=c(10.00,9.00,29.50,-7.50,-11.00))

sales$Salesman<-reorder(sales$Salesman,-sales$ProfitLoss,function(z) sum(abs(z)))

    ggplot(sales, aes(x = factor(Salesman), y = ProfitLoss)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="dodge",color="white")
```

[image]

Comment: See my update.  If no one answers by tomorrow, I'll select your solution as correct since you did answer my original post.